# How do I fix verify certificate error when connecting to an AWS Client VPN endpoint?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ipsec

I have setup a Client VPN, using steps described in [Create a Client VPN Endpoint](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpn/latest/clientvpn-admin/cvpn-working-endpoints.html#cvpn-working-endpoint-create).

For the server certificate, I picked a public certificate that was newly created and verified by AWS Certificate Manager.

I configured the authentication method to be `Use Active Directory authentication` with a Directory ID that corresponds to an AWS SimpleAD directory.

I left the Transport Protocol set to UDP.

When I download the client configuration and try connecting via Tunnelblick (v3.7.8) on OSX, I get the following error:

```
VERIFY ERROR: depth=3, error=unable to get issuer certificate: C=US, ST=Arizona, L=Scottsdale, O=Starfield Technologies, Inc., CN=Starfield Services Root Certificate Authority - G2
OpenSSL: error:14090086:SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed
TLS_ERROR: BIO read tls_read_plaintext error
TLS Error: TLS object -> incoming plaintext read error
TLS Error: TLS handshake failed
```

Any ideas what is not configured correctly or what I could do to resolve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like the *Certificate Authority Root Certificate* wasn't properly imported into your client. Hence it can't verify the *Server Certificate* (against any valid *Root CA Cert*) and complains about `ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed`.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Is that typically defined in the ovpn file or somewhere else?

Comment: @JimGeurts Yes it’s the `ca` parameter in your ovpn file.

Comment: Looks like there might be a bug in AWS Certificate Manager or in the Client VPN endpoint export. I edited the ovpn file and replaced the root from the certificate and things worked. Thanks for the help!

Comment: would you mind to elaborate a bit the solution? not an expert here, trying to connect AWS ClientVPN but getting `VERIFY ERROR: depth=3, error=unable to get local issuer certificate: C=US, ST=Arizona, L=Scottsdale, O=Starfield Technologies, Inc., CN=Starfield Services Root Certificate Authority - G2`

Answer (score 5):

Further to the [answer by Maruthi](https://serverfault.com/a/984545/591057) - I would comment, but don't have enough reputation...

Here is a similar **[official answer from AWS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpn/latest/clientvpn-user/windows-troubleshooting.html#windows-troubleshooting-openvpn-connect)**

[image]

But, crucially, they specify replacing the 3rd certificate in the ovpn file, and not the last certificate.

> Cause

> Certificate Authority (CA) chain information is missing in the Client VPN configuration file provided by Amazon, which causes validation to fail.

> This issue can occur for certificates generated by AWS Certificate Manager.

> Solution

> Open the Client VPN configuration file (the .ovpn file) and replace the third certificate in the  section in with the following certificate, and then save the file.

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

> Import the updated configuration file to the OpenVPN Connect Client software and connect to the Client VPN endpoint.

Replacing the last certificate did not work for me, but replacing the 3rd certificate did and finally fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 4):

Copying an answer from reddit that worked for me: https://www.reddit.com/r/aws/comments/aeohf5/any_ideas_to_successfully_connect_to_an_aws/

> I have support and opened a case with them. They told me to replace the last cert in the .opvn file with the following root cert. It works. Don't forget to create add the random host name to the `cvpn...` name :

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Comment: Hi, please add detail, as link-only answer can because obsolete with time, thanks !

Comment: @yagmoth555 appreciate your comment and corrected my answer but I don't deserve a down vote for finding the answer elsewhere, verifying it and bringing it onto this platform in any form so it can help people.

Comment: Hi, I undertsand your view, it's just that we see soo much answers that the information is no longer available on the internet or the internet archive, it's sad, or even that it's a link gooing to a page with advertising, so the link is done on bad purpose. People tend to downvote for that, as they would not want to follow. A downvote don't need a comment, as such it's why I left you a comment, as I understanded it's a good info you found, but I explain the why your answer can attract upvote.

Comment: Using https://www.sslshopper.com/certificate-decoder.html the certificate translates as:
Common Name: Starfield Services Root Certificate Authority - G2
Organization: Starfield Technologies, Inc.
Locality: Scottsdale
State: Arizona
Country: US
Valid From: August 31, 2009
Valid To: December 31, 2037
Issuer: Starfield Services Root Certificate Authority - G2, Starfield Technologies, Inc.
Serial Number: 0 (0x0)

Comment: I checksum'd the last cert in my .ovpn file with the one posted in this answer. They're exactly the same. My client still won't accept it.

Comment: In my case, I replaced third cert with this one https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpn/latest/clientvpn-user/macos-troubleshooting.html

Answer (score 3):

Due to lack of reputation I cannot add a comment to the accepted answer. Further to @Matthew Brophy's answer simply *remove* the third certificate entry if you have 4. The final .. block worked for me:

```
<ca>
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
</ca>
```

Comment: I do not understand what the "The final .. block worked for me:" means - what does ".." mean?

Answer (score 2):

The solution:

1. Download certificate from Starfield Technologies repository. The file you need is [sf-class2-root.crt](https://certs.secureserver.net/repository/sf-class2-root.crt). This is a text file, it contains the certificate you need.
2. Open VPN client config file ***.ovpn** with text editor, find `<ca> ... </ca>` section and paste the content of the **sf-class2-root.crt** file to the end of `<ca> ... </ca>` section (after other certificates).
3. Reimport updated ***.ovpn** file to the client VPN software and reconnect.

Answer (score 1):

I've found exactly what is required for this to work.

I had the VPN setup to use SSO with Google, so I needed to use AWS VPN client.

Downloading the Client Configuration from AWS Console and adding the profile on a Windows PC worked flawlessly. Doing the same from a Mac returned an immediate TLS handshake error.

The logs also returned OP's "unable to get issuer certificate".

You need to edit the ovpn file, it has 4 certificates and the third one is causing the issue. You need to remove it so the only certificates are the following:

```
<ca>
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
</ca>
```